# Hacking into a simple linux server

Tags: linux

I'm very new to hacking in general so I wanted to learn more. I have an exercise, whereby we have a raspberry pi with a simple website on it and we have to get a file and the stored gpg private key on the raspberry pi. It's a beginner's question so the solution should be very easy but I don't know which aspects to focus on. So far I've ran nmap on the raspberry pi and it shows that ports 22 and 80 are open. I've tried using ncrack but it takes more than 5 hours, to no avail.

Any ideas what I should look out for?

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably getting down voted is because it is difficult to answer these types of questions. Did you just randomly place a file somewhere on the Raspberry Pi filesystem and expect to get it? If you would like to get into these types of things I suggest downloading vulnerable VMs on sites like VulnHub where they give you challenges as per your question - the difference is that these are created in a way that allows you to actually hack it (i.e vulnerable SSH servers etc.)

Comment: Kind of impossible to answer properly, as we can't see the challenge. I'd start by poking around the website (Assuming there's an HTTP server on port 80). Check the robots.txt file, look for login pages etc. Try connecting to port 22  and see what you get. come back with more details if you find something.

Comment: Your question is offtopic... StackExchange isn't a coursework help website. When you have exercises, odds are you're expected to complete them on your own to learn anything at all, and if you don't know where to start you should really go back to your course materials.

Answer (score 3):

from what I can tell you are playing a CTF game, you are most likely meant to find a vulnerability within the web application to pull a file off the server and thats either it or these files are then meant to give you access to the ssh.

This is my assumption, look on the web application for any file requests or text boxes and go in from there.

expanding my answer further:

The most common CTF is getting the passwd file ../../../../../../../passwd or you can try and get the source code and reverse engineer the system step by step. this is the best answer I can give based upon the information provided. if this is task given and the linux box came with ports 22 / 80 ssh was probably used to modify the original FS so it could then be duplicated and distributed so I am going to suggest you concentrate solely on the webapp. (and maybe a few default usernames and passwords on the ssh connection. admin/admin admin/password admin/12345 etc etc

Comment: This does not answer the question. Yes, I know that it is hard to answer the question with the vague problem description which is provided: That's why the question is on hold as too broad. You really shouldn't try to answer questions which do not have enough information to be answerable yet. You will have to guess, which means that the answer will not be helpful for the person who asks or for any future visitors. Instead, post comments asking the question author to be more specific.

Comment: @Philipp I am going to have to disagree with you here, but dont get me wrong I do see your very valid point, I think from experience of playing these games and the information provided I can make a good enough assumption to provide this answer as a suitable answer through sheer logic alone. if he has to crack a linux box with a web application on it and has to capture a bit of important information I can assuringly answer that he has to go through the web app and search for url / user input that he can modify as step 1. I will amend my answer if anything further arises.